# Screen scrambled after update with Intel GMA HD Graphics

Tags: 11.10, intel

Today my laptop froze after it waking up. I rebooted my laptop, saw the grub screen, hit enter, and then everything got scrambled as seen below:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Pisfh (sorry, not enough karma to embed)]

This scrambling is not confined to the splash screen. It persists after logging in. I restarted and booted windows 7 without issues. This leads me to believe that the cause is some funky driver update.

Has anyone else experienced this? I've tried running 'dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg' from the command line. I've also purged the xserver-xorg package and resinstalled it. Any ideas? Can I maybe roll back the driver to a previous version (assuming that is the case)? If so what package contains the Intel graphics drivers?

Comment: can you check whether the shape of the distortion changes when you change resolution? I guess it is an unsupported resolution / refresh rate, or better a not functioning one in your driver version.

Comment: Nope, same distortion just at a lower resolution.

Comment: I just re-installed Ubuntu. Everything worked fine. Then I updated it, restarted, and now I'm back at square 1. This is a freshly updated base install with no 3rd party packages.

Comment: I've narrowed this down to a problem with the kernel. It happens after upgrading from the 3.0.0.14 to 3.0.0.15 kernel. I've filed a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/925228