# Screen flickering / scrambling on an Asus UL30A

Tags: flicker

Recently my Laptop screen started to flicker.

- You can view the phenomena here: [YouTube](http://youtu.be/hQYn3LROD5s)
- Sometimes the screen is totally scrambled, but most of the time it starts with the Title bar only.
- It happens inconsistently.

My Laptop is Asus UL30A and I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Output from command:

```
sudo lshw -C display; lsb_release -a; uname -a; xrandr

  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:fe400000-fe7fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:dc00(size=8)
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe800000-fe8fffff
LSB Version:    core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:    11.10
Codename:   oneiric
Linux steelke 3.0.0-14-generic-pae #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 22:07:10 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 164mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I already rolled back the kernel to 3.0.0-14 instead of 3.0.0-17 as mentioned in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100485/screen-scrambled-after-update-with-intel-gma-hd-graphics) post, but without result.

I guess the problem is related to the driver, because I don't see similar behaviour in the BIOS Setup.

Any tips or help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

My computer is ASUS A43E. I saw your youtube video. Mine was https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1008322?comments=all

Since one week I did not have all those kind of screen nuisance anymore. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 unity 3d 32 bit. Upgrading to 12.04 since day one, and updating regularly. I think, our friends in Ubuntu community has solved the problem.

You may want to try 12.04. I have tried to consistently using it since 11.04. I think, Unity is quite stable now and does have productivity boosting effect. Still some inconsistency with LibreOffice menu sometime. But we can consider it stable and good.